# Magento 2 change Footer Text color

Tags: magento2, theme, less

How can i change the footer text color in .less file? 
Which variable is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `@footer-links-color`.

for example, in `{theme_dir}/web/css/source/_extend.less`:

`@footer-links-color: blue;`

You then need to recompile the css:

```
rm -rf pub/static/* var/view_preprocessed/*
```